# MySQL fails to restart on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, server, mysql

I'm following this guide:

http://kodi.wiki/view/MySQL/Setting_up_MySQL#tab=Ubuntu_Linux

The aim is to use mysql network file sharing so that I can view the media on my Raspberry Pi OSMC on Kodi installs on other network devices. I'd prefer not to use UPnP because it is poor at integrating libraries within Kodi.

I get the following failure message on step 4:

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
[sudo] password for ms: 
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status mysql.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
```

Here's the output from "systemctl  status mysql.service" and "journalctl  -xe":

```
$ systemctl  status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-01-25 21:0
  Process: 2323 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2317 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exit
 Main PID: 2323 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE); Control PID: 2324 (mysql-system
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
           ├─2324 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
           └─2418 sleep 1

Jan 25 21:06:54 ms-ThinkPad-T530 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Jan 25 21:06:56 ms-ThinkPad-T530 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited,
lines 1-14/14 (END)
```

and then:

```
$ journalctl  -xe
Jan 25 21:17:04 ms-ThinkPad-T530 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 25 21:17:04 ms-ThinkPad-T530 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 25 21:17:04 ms-ThinkPad-T530 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 25 21:17:04 ms-ThinkPad-T530 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Jan 25 21:17:04 ms-ThinkPad-T530 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Jan 25 21:17:04 ms-ThinkPad-T530 audit[4291]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="
Jan 25 21:17:04 ms-ThinkPad-T530 audit[4291]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="
Jan 25 21:17:04 ms-ThinkPad-T530 audit[4291]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="
Jan 25 21:17:04 ms-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1516911424.598:104): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open
Jan 25 21:17:04 ms-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1516911424.598:105): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open
Jan 25 21:17:04 ms-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1516911424.598:106): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open
Jan 25 21:17:06 ms-ThinkPad-T530 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Anyone any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` and adding the lines:

```
/proc/*/status r,
/sys/devices/system/node/ r,
/sys/devices/system/node/node0/meminfo r,
```

Your `journalctl -xe` output is cut off, so I can only guess the files it is trying to access. The names of the files and directories it wants to access comes after the `name="` part. You can always repost your output of `journalctl -xe`, and I can help you further.

2 things to note with the AppArmor config file. The `r,` at the end of the line gives read access. The `/` at the end of line two indicates you are giving read access to a directory, not just a file.

Finally, let's restart a couple of things :

```
sudo service apparmor reload
sudo service mysql restart
```

P.S., your `/var/log/syslog` may provide additional information about what files MySQL and AppArmor are having trouble with.

P.P.S., this [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/apparmor-and-mysql) by Jeremy Smyth may be useful to you. It suggests a couple of other methods to fix/diagnose your problem that I have not covered here.

Comment: So before doing anything, I ran `journalctl -xe` again: https://pastebin.com/861QjJRq.

Following you suggestions apparmour reload works but mysql restart returns the same error message from earlier. Outputs  this time:

`systemctl  status mysql.service`:
https://pastebin.com/sQUwjWNd

`journalctl  -xe`:
https://pastebin.com/Ffic7D2A

and the syslog
https://pastebin.com/cS8KJZPR

Thanks for your help on this!